# How to return from a function after callback succeded?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, viewmodel

In my viewmodel I have a function which returns a NoDataResult. The function has a callback `BleStateCallback`.

At the moment, as soon as the function is called it returns `NoDataFailure(RuntimeException("Not today, buddy"))` as I have set that as the default value.

But I only want to return when callback methods are executed `onBleDeviceStateChange` based on `when state`.

Here is my function.

```kotlin
private fun connectToCharger(activity: Activity): NoDataResult {
    var result: NoDataResult = NoDataFailure(RuntimeException("Not today, buddy"))

    blufiHelper.scanForDevicesAndConnectTohomeCharger(
        activity,
        "homewifi1",
        object : BleStateCallback {
            override fun updateMessage(message: String) {
                // use livedata to update ui
                Timber.d("xxx VM $message")
            }

            override fun onBleDeviceStateChange(state: BleDeviceState) {
                Timber.d("xxx VM onBleDeviceStateChange $state")
                result = when (state) {
                    BleDeviceState.Connected -> NoDataSuccess
                    BleDeviceState.Disconnected -> NoDataFailure(RuntimeException("Not today, buddy"))
                    else -> NoDataFailure(RuntimeException("Not today, buddy"))
                }
            }
        })
    Timber.d("xxx VM RETURNING")
    return result
}
```

Comment: You have to have an object that the original function can wait on and that the callback would signal.  For example a Flow, RXJava object, or Semaphore.  Create it in the base function, await for it after calling scan, and signal it in the callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API or launches a coroutine return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o)

Answer (score 0):

You tell the function to return your default value and so it does. Your callback won't do anything anymore when invoked by `scanForDevicesAndConnectTohomeCharger` because it's too late.

You would have to pass a `BleStateCallback` from your activity to then react to a callback to `onBleDeviceStateChange` accordingly.

But I highly recommend to check out how `Activities` and `ViewModel` are supposed to play together. Especially in your scenario it would be recommended to introduce a `LiveData` that holds your `BleDeviceState` (initial state and ongoing changes), and your activity will simply observe this exposed LiveData and react to that.